# Open an image in Paint, saving the image and closing Paint using C#

Tags: c#, image, paint

As stated in the title of the question I have a doubt regarding Paint.

In C# I would like to:

1- Open an existent .jpg image in Paint

2- Save the image in the same format using Paint

3- Leave Paint open for 1 second

4- Close Paint

So far I only know how to do the first step and I have no idea about how to do the rest.

You help is greatly appreciated!

```
        string path = "C:/blah blah";
        String image = "imageInput.jpg";
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(image);
        startInfo.Verb = "edit";
        Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to open it and save it in the same format? Why use paint for this? C# has built-in classes that can do exactly what you want without paint...

Comment: It is because I have another bit of "dirty" code which uses OpenCV that can only run if the image has been previously saved with Paint (I have already tried the built-in classes without success). This is why I am looking for the quick workaround explained above.

Answer (score 0):

You should really look and see what Paint is doing differently than the normal C# routines.  I am guessing it is adding/changing some meta data.  If this is true you could just change the metadata with a program instead of opening this in paint.  I don't believe Paint has the auto-save that you are looking for.